# Prove that $\prod_{i<j} (p_i^{p_j}-p_j^{p_i})$ is divisible by $5777$

Tags: number-theory

> We are given $2017$ prime numbers $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{2017}$. Prove that  $\displaystyle \prod_{i<j} (p_i^{p_j}-p_j^{p_i})$ is divisible by $5777$.

Note that $5777 = 53 \cdot 109$. We first consider $p_i^{p_j}-p_j^{p_i}$ modulo $53$. We are to prove that \begin{align*}p_i^{p_j} \equiv p_j^{p_i} \pmod{53} \quad \tag{1}\end{align*} for some primes $p_i,p_j$.There exist primes in the list such that $p_i = 53k_1+d,p_j = 53k_2+d$, where $0 \leq d \leq 52$ and $k_1,k_2 > 0$. Then $(1)$ is equivalent to $$d^{53k_1} \equiv d^{53k_2} \pmod{53} \iff d^{53(k_1-k_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{53}.$$ Now since $53$ is odd, $k_1,k_2$ must be only odd or only even. Then note there are at least $2017-15 = 2002$ such primes $p_i,p_j$ because there are $28$ primes between $0$ and $53$. Therefore, since $\left\lceil\dfrac{2002}{53}\right\rceil = 39$, there exist $p_i,p_j$ such that $k_1 \equiv k_2 \pmod{26}$ and $k_1$ and $k_2$ have the same parity quotient upon division by $26$ and $k_1 > k_2$. Therefore, $$52 \mid 53(k_1-k_2)$$ and so we have found primes $p_i,p_j$ that satisfy $(1)$.

I tried proving divisibility by $109$ using the same argument, but it didn't work:

Now we consider modulo $109$. We are to prove that \begin{align*}p_i^{p_j} \equiv p_j^{p_i} \pmod{109} \quad \tag{2}\end{align*} for some primes $p_i,p_j$. primes in the list such that $p_i = 109m_1+d_1,p_j = 109m_2+d_1$, where $0 \leq d_1 \leq 108$ and $m_1,m_2 > 0$. Then $(2)$ is equivalent to $$d_1^{109m_1} \equiv d_1^{109m_2} \pmod{109} \iff d_1^{109(m_1-m_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{109}.$$ Now since $109$ is odd, $m_1,m_2$ must be only odd or only even. Then note there are at least $2017-28 = 1989$ such primes $p_i,p_j$ because there are $28$ primes between $0$ and $109$. Therefore, $\left\lceil\dfrac{1989}{109}\right\rceil = 19$.

Is it possible to use the same argument to prove divisibility by $109$?

Comment: Are the prime numbers *any* prime numbers or the first 2017 prime numbers.  Can was assume 53 and 109 are among the primes?

Comment: @fleablood We are given the $2017$ primes, so they aren't necessarily the first $2017$ primes.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Unfortunately, you haven't even proven it's true for $53$. This is since "... there exist $p_i,p_j$ such that $k_1 \equiv k_2 \pmod{26}$ and $k_1$ and $k_2$ have the same parity quotient upon division by $26$ and $k_1 > k_2$. Therefore, $52 \mid 53(k_1-k_2)$" isn't necessarily true. For example, let $k_1 = 28$ & $k_2 = 2$. In this case, $k_1 \equiv k_2 \pmod{26}$, have the same parity, but as $k_1-k_2 = 26$, then $52 \not\mid 53(k_1-k_2)$. It's likely whatever method is used to prove it for $109$ can also be used for the $53$ case. I've tried a few things, but no success so far.

Comment: Are you only interested in commentary on your approach or are you interested in other approaches?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like there are too many pigeons in this problem. We can assume that all the $p_i$ are distinct otherwise for $p_i=p_j, i<j$ the product in question is $0$ hence a multiple of $5777$.

In particular, the idea is to see when two primes $p,q$ satisfy $53 | p^q-q^p$ and $109 | p^q-q^p$ respectively, then transform this accordingly into an argument which allows the use of pigeonhole principle.

Eveerything the OP has done for $53$ fails for $109$ because the problem is that the number of pigeonholes isn't constrained enough while the number of pigeons stays the same.

The idea for both $53$ and $109$ seems to be the following. Suppose, without loss of generality that $p,q$ are two primes such that $p,q$ do not divide $108$ or $109$. In that case, $p,q$ are coprime to $108$ and by Bezout's lemma , we can find non-negative $p',q'$ such that $$pp' \equiv qq' \equiv 1 \pmod{108}$$

Once this is done, then for such $p,q$ as above, the following implication
holds : $$
p^{p'} \equiv q^{q'} \pmod{109} \implies p^q \equiv q^p \pmod{109}
$$
Indeed, begin with primes $p,q$ coprime to $108,109$ such that $p^{p'} \equiv q^{q'} \pmod{109}$. Then, raise both sides to the power $pq$ to get $$
p^{p'pq} \equiv q^{q'qp} \pmod{109} \tag{1} \label{1}
$$

However, by Fermat's little theorem, $p^{108} \equiv 1 \pmod{109}$ because $p \neq 109$. Similarly, $p^{108k+1} \equiv p \pmod{109}$ for any $k \geq 1$. In particular, as $pp' = 108k+1$ for some $k \geq 1$,
$$
p^{p'p} \equiv p \pmod{109} \implies p^{p'pq} \equiv p^q \pmod{109}
$$

Repeating this with $q$ tells us that $q^{q'qp} \equiv q^p \pmod{109}$. Going back to \eqref{1}, we get to $p^q \equiv q^p \pmod{109}$, as desired.

Therefore, we are reduced to merely looking at $p_i^{p_i'}$ for all $i$ such that $p_i$ is coprime to all of $52,53,108$ and $109$. That's just the primes $2,3,13,53,109$, so taking these out we have at least $2012$ primes to work with.

---

Taking those out, we have $2012$ pigeons, which are $p_i^{p_i'}$ for $i=1,\ldots,2012$. We have only $109$ pigeonholes which are remainders of these quotients modulo $109$. By PHP we can find $i<j$ such that $p_i^{p_{i}'} \equiv p_j^{p_j'} \pmod{109}$. As $p_i,p_j \neq 2,3,13,53,109$, it follows that $p_i^{p_j} \equiv p_j^{p_i} \pmod{109}$ for this choice of $i$ and $j$.

For a possible different choice of $i$ and $j$, but with $53$ instead of $109$, we will get that some $i<j$ exist such that $p_i^{p_j} \equiv p_j^{p_i} \pmod{53}$.

As $5777 = 109 \times 53$ is the product of these two primes, it follows that $5777$ is also a multiple of the product. However, $2017$ seems like an unusually large number of pigeons and it almost seems bewildering to have so many unnecessary pigeons in a "tough" PHP problem. I can't see anything wrong with my solution immediately, though.

Comment: In fact, we can simplify it to "For 110 integers $a_i$, $\prod (a_i - a_j ) $ is a multiple of 109 by using PHP on the remainders mod 109, then set $ a_ i = {p_i} ^ { p_i } $. $\quad$ There is no need to reference FLT or cast out small primes.

Comment: @CalvinLin You're right, it seems that there is no need to throw out the "bad" numbers. I will edit the answer with that remark once I frame it carefully. I am very, very surprised about the downvotes on your answer below, consider flagging for mod attention.

Comment: It's unclear to me how $p'$ and $q'$ are generated and you seem to claim that $p^q \equiv q^p$ for any choice of $p,q$, which clearly not true.

Comment: @Joffan By (suitably extending) Bezout's lemma, if $p$ is coprime to $108$ then there exist positive integers $a,b$ such that $ap-1=108b$ and one can take $p' = a$ so that $pp' \equiv 1 \pmod{108}$. A similar logic yields $q'$ for $q$. The next line claims that *if* $p^{p'} \equiv q^{q'} \pmod{109}$ *then* $p^q \equiv q^p \pmod{109}$ provided that $p,q$ don't divide $108$, and this is clear from the explanation on the line after that.  Clearly $p^{p'} \equiv q^{q'} \pmod{109}$ need not hold for all $p,q$ but if you take a large enough bunch of them then PHP comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\eqvm}[1]{\underset{\small #1}{\equiv}}$
As already observed, $5777=53\times 109$. We can prove for divisibility of $P_T:=\displaystyle \prod_{i<j} (p_i^{p_j}-p_j^{p_i})$ by $53$ easily and then adapt the method for $109$.

If we have two primes $p$ and $q$ such that both $p \eqvm{53} q$ and $p \eqvm{52}q$, then it is clear from Fermat's Little Theorem that $p^q \eqvm{53} q^p$. If we discard primes $2, 13$ and $53$ (if among the given primes), all other primes are coprime to both $53$ and $52$, meaning a choice of $\phi(53)\phi(52)=52\cdot 24 = 1248$ possible different combination values of $\bmod (53,52)$, and we have at least $2014$ primes to consider, so by the pigeonhole principle we will have $p^q - q^p\eqvm{53} 0$ for some $p,q$ in the set (in fact for hundreds of cases).

If we attempt to use the same process for divisibility by $109$, we end up with $\phi(109)\phi(108)=$ $108\cdot 36 =3888$ pigeonholes; too many for our $2014$ pigeons (since $108=2^23^3$, we may be excluding $2,3$ and $109$ this time, if present).

But we can reduce the number of pigeonholes by considering the multiplicative order of each possible equivalence class $\bmod 109$. $1$ only has one slot available, since $1^j \equiv 1^k$ for any $j,k$. Also $108^j \equiv 108^k$ for any $j,k$ in our permitted primes, since they are all odd. The two order-$3$ values, $\{45,63\}$, create $2$ cases each and likewise the $2$ order-$4$ values $\{76,33\}$. The $2$ order-$6$ values $\{46,64\}$ also have two cases, since all exponents are $1$ or $5 \bmod 6$. The $6$ order-$9$ and $6$ order-$18$ have $6$ cases each, $4$ order-$12$ have $4$ cases, $18$ order-$27$ and $18$ order-$54$ have $18$ cases each, $12$ order-$36$ have $12$ cases and finally the $36$ order-$108$ primitive roots have $36$ cases each. This brings the total pigeonhole count to $1+1+4+4+36+36+16+324+324+144+1296=2190$.

Still too many pigeonholes. However let's look at the primitive root set (order-$109$) $\{6,10,11,13,$ $14,18,24,30,$ $37,39,40,42,$ $44,47,50,51,$ $52,53,56,57,$ $58,59,62,65,$ $67,69,70,72,$ $79,85,91,95,$ $96,98,99,103\}$ a little more and show that we can fill only (at most) half those pigeonholes. So far we have only considering that for $p \eqvm{(109,108)} (p_d,p_o)$ we cannot allow a $q \eqvm{(109,108)} (p_d,p_o)$. However if we consider some other $q \eqvm{(109,108)} (q_d,q_o)$ this may still be ineligible if $p_d^{q_o} 
\eqvm{109}  q_d^{p_o}$. And in fact because we are dealing with only primes which are coprime to $108$, every solution to $p_d^{q_o}$ is a primitive root too and for each $(p_d,p_o)$ there is always a corresponding valid $q_o$ for each of the $35$ other $q_d$ classes $\bmod 108$ in the primitive root set. So for example if we have a prime $p\eqvm{(109,108)} (11,5)$ then $\color{red}{11}^{43} \eqvm{109} 6^{\color{red}5}$, $\color{red}{11}^{103} \eqvm{109} 10^{\color{red}5}$, $\color{red}{11}^{73} \eqvm{109} 13^{\color{red}5}$, etc. So choosing $p\equiv (11,5)$ eliminates choices $(6,43), (10,103), (13,73)$, etc covering all other primitive roots$\bmod 109$. Thus if we chose all $36$ possibilities for $11 \bmod 109$ we would not be able to use any choices at all from other primitive root classes. The best we could hope for is to choose $18$ options for each primitive root which eliminates the other $18$ options for all other primitive roots, giving $18\cdot 36=648$ options and thus we now have more prime pigeons $(2014)$ than available pigeonholes (now $1542$), so $P_T$ is indeed divisible by $109$.

---

---

An "after-proof" thought:

"The best we could hope for" relies on the possibility that the exclusion relation between candidate primes is not *transitive*, but experimentally this is not the case. In the example for excluded cases from $(11,5)$ above, we find $13^{43} \eqvm{109} 6^{73}$, for example. In fact using $a'$ to denote the multiplicative inverse of $a\bmod 108$, we can see that
$p^{q} \eqvm{109}  q^{p} \iff p^{p'} \eqvm{109}  q^{q'}$. This ensures that exclusion is always transitive and we thus only actually have $36$ "pigeonholes" for the primitive root cases. Likewise using inverses to the multiplicative order of each class in turn, there are only $108$ pigeonholes overall.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Among the 2017 primes, there are a pair which is same modulo 53 and another pair which is same modulo 109.
Edit: Even if $p_i$ equals $p_j$ modulo 53, we don't know if $p_i^{p_j}-p_j^{p_i}$ is divisible by 53.

Comment: That's not enough, either, because of raising everything to different powers. But it is the start of the trail.

Comment: @Joffan I think it is enough. $p^q \equiv p \pmod q$ if $q$ is prime

Comment: What we need is $ p \equiv q \pmod{52}$ in order to definitively conclude that $ p ^ q \equiv p^p \equiv q^p$. EG With $ p = 2, q = 11$, $2^{11} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ and $ 11^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Answer (score -1):

We can simplify Sarvesh's approach to proving the following:

> Given $n+1$ integers $a_i$, then there is some $i, j$ such that $ n \mid (a_i - a_j)$.

Proof: Consider the remainders of $a_i \pmod{n}$. Since there are $n+1$ terms, and $n$ possible remainders, by PHP 2 of them are the same. Hence $ n \mid a_i - a_j$.

---

Now apply this to $n = 53,$ (resp 109).
If any of the $p_i = 53, 109$, let's ignore them.
Let $a_i = {p_i} ^ { 1/p_i}$, where the rational exponent is interpreted mod 53 (resp 109) so we have an integer. These exist and are well defined in prime modulus as they have a generator.
Then, by the above, there is some $i,j$ such that $p_i^{1/p_i} \equiv p_j ^{1/p_j} \pmod{53}$. Raising the expoenets by $p_i p_j$, we get that $ p_i^{p_j} \equiv p_j^{p_i} \pmod{53}$.
Hence, we only need 112 prime numbers to draw the conclusion.

Note: To extend this to all integers

- We exclude multiples of 53 (resp 109). However, if there are 2 or more such multiples, then clearly $ p_i^{p_j} - p_j^{p_i}$ is a multiple of 53.
- The rest hold, and so we do only need 112 integers.

Comment: Interesting, why all the downvotes?

Comment: I think you misread the question. The term in the product should be $p_i ^ {p_j} - p_j ^ {p_i}$. (Look carefully at the exponents)

Comment: @suncup224 OHHHH. I def missed that. Now, let me fix it...... Thanks!